# Encrypted save and decrypted load of an ArrayList of serializable objects

Tags: java, android, encryption, file-io

I save and load in sd card a file that contains an `ArrayList` of serializable object with these two methods

save method

```
public static void saveUserList(ArrayList<User> userList) {
        if (storageAvailable()) {
            try {
                createFolder();

                FileOutputStream userList = new FileOutputStream(
                        baseDir + File.separator + baseAppDir + File.separator
                                + fileName);

                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                        userList);
                oos.writeObject(userList);

                oos.close();
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

load method

```
 public static ArrayList<User> loadUserList() {
        if (storageAvailable()) {
            ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
            try {
                FileInputStream userList = new FileInputStream(baseDir
                        + File.separator + baseAppDir + File.separator
                        + fileName);

                ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(
                        userList);

                userList = (ArrayList<User>) oos.readObject();
                oos.close();

            } catch (Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }

            return userList;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Now I want that the method `saveUserList` encrypts the content of the file during the save according a specific `String keyword` and the method `loadUserList` decrypts the file with the same keyword to return the arrayList.

How could I do this?
I have given a look to `CipherOutputStream` but I haven't understood how should I use this.

The method proposed to use Conceal library

```
public static void saveUserListCrypted(ArrayList<User> userList) {
    if (storageAvailable()) {
        try {
            createFolder();
            Crypto crypto = new Crypto(
                new SharedPrefsBackedKeyChain(context),
                new SystemNativeCryptoLibrary());

            FileOutputStream userList = new FileOutputStream(
                    baseDir + File.separator + baseAppDir + File.separator
                            + fileName);

            OutputStream cryptedStream = crypto.getCipherOutputStream(
                userList, new Entity("UserList");


            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    cryptedStream);
            oos.writeObject(userList);

            oos.close();
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

cause this error

```
 this error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException 02-12 21:29:05.026 2051-2051/com.myapp W/System.err﹕ at com.facebook.crypto.streams.NativeGCMCipherOutputStream.write
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try (adding the appropriate checks and try blocks that I have omitted to make the code more readable) something like this to save

```
public static void AESObjectEncoder(Serializable object, String password, String path) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = null;
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, fromStringToAESkey(password));
            SealedObject sealedObject = null;
            sealedObject = new SealedObject(object, cipher);
            CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = null;
            cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path)), cipher);
            ObjectOutputStream outputStream = null;
            outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(cipherOutputStream);
            outputStream.writeObject(sealedObject);
            outputStream.close();    
    }
```

and this to load

```
 public static Serializable AESObjectDedcoder(String password, String path) {
        Cipher cipher = null;
        Serializable userList = null;
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Pdding");

        //Code to write your object to file
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, fromStringToAESkey(password));         
        CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = null;
        cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path)), cipher);

        ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;
        inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(cipherInputStream);
        SealedObject sealedObject = null;
        sealedObject = (SealedObject) inputStream.readObject();
        userList = (Serializable) sealedObject.getObject(ciper);  
        return userList;
    }
```

to create a `SecretKey` from a String you can use this

```
public static SecretKey fromStringToAESkey(String s) {
        //256bit key need 32 byte
        byte[] rawKey = new byte[32];
        // if you don't specify the encoding you might get weird results
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[0];
        try {
            keyBytes = s.getBytes("ASCII");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.arraycopy(keyBytes, 0, rawKey, 0, keyBytes.length);
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(rawKey, "AES");
        return key;
    }
```

*NOTE:*

*this code encrypts and decrypts twice to show the way of use of both sealed object and Cipher streams*

Comment: thanks but unfortunately i get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cipher not initialized`

Comment: mmm...create a new question with more details about the error

Comment: I would replace fromStringToAESkey with a standard key derivation function like PBKDF. This will usually give better distributed keys.

Comment: Why would you encrypt and decrypt twice? And does this really work? The states of the Cipher objects won't marry up correctly, for a start.

Comment: encrypt and decrypt twice to show the way of use of both sealed object and Cipher streams, however this works the same. you can try and see yourself before downvote.
Only basilar adjustments (like proper try-catch blocks) are needed to compile this code.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest taking a look at Conceal, recently released by facebook: http://facebook.github.io/conceal/

This should be a trivial modification to wrap a Conceal output stream with an ObjectOutputStream used in your current code:

```
public static void saveUserList(ArrayList<User> userList) {
    if (storageAvailable()) {
        try {
            createFolder();
            Crypto crypto = new Crypto(
                new SharedPrefsBackedKeyChain(context),
                new SystemNativeCryptoLibrary());

            FileOutputStream userList = new FileOutputStream(
                    baseDir + File.separator + baseAppDir + File.separator
                            + fileName);

            OutputStream cryptedStream = crypto.getCipherOutputStream(
                userList, new Entity("UserList");


            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    cryptedStream);
            oos.writeObject(userList);

            oos.close();
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I'll leave the restore as an exercise for the reader. ;)

Comment: thanks for the answer, could you give me more details about this implementation? the key is the Context? If yes, if I try to call a similar restore method from another Activity cannot decrypt?

Comment: No. The keys are stored in a SharedPreference backend which is accessible from all Activities. Read the docs on the library for more information.

Comment: I have tried but get this error `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
02-12 21:29:05.026    2051-2051/com.myapp W/System.err﹕ at com.facebook.crypto.streams.NativeGCMCipherOutputStream.write`

Comment: Do you have the native libraries linked? Regardless, I suggest opening a new question with more information about this particular error.

Comment: I have added the native libraries in `libs` folder with their respective 'armeabi`, `armeabi=v7` and `x86` sub-folders. Is there something that I have missing?

Comment: Check the source: https://github.com/facebook/conceal/blob/master/java/com/facebook/crypto/streams/NativeGCMCipherOutputStream.java

Apparently they have not written the `write(int)` method. 
ObjectOuputStream uses this method. That method is easy enough to implement using the `write(byte[], int, int)` methods if you edit the source code. You probably want to use a `byte[]` member and declare the method synchronized to avoid thrashing the GC on every write.

Comment: Sorry but I haven't understood... in your proposed code I don't see any `write(int)` and is unclear, why and how, I shoud edit the `NativeGCMCipherOutputStream ` of the library

Comment: The implementation itself is not currently supporting the write(int) method in NativeGCMCipherOutputStream. You need to either implement that method, or alternatively write all of your objects to a memory buffer of bytes and then write to the encrypted output stream.

Comment: Can you post your entire stack trace as an issue on the Conceal github project https://github.com/facebook/conceal/issues?state=open.

I can help take a look.

Comment: This has been fixed, and there is now an implementation of write(), so it should just work with the latest version of Conceal

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use AES Encoding:

```
private static byte[] getEncrypt(final String key, final String message) throws GeneralSecurityException {
  final byte[] rawData = key.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
  if (rawData.length != 16) {
    // If this is not 16 in length, there's a problem with the key size, nothing to do here
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("You've provided an invalid key size");
  }

  final SecretKeySpec seckeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(rawData, "AES");
  final Cipher ciph = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

  ciph.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, seckeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
  return ciph.doFinal(message.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")));
}

private static String getDecrypt(String key, byte[] encrypted) throws GeneralSecurityException {
  final byte[] rawData = key.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
  if (rawData.length != 16) {
    // If this is not 16 in length, there's a problem with the key size, nothing to do here
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid key size.");
  }

  final SecretKeySpec seckeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(rawData, "AES");

  final Cipher ciph = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
  ciph.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, seckeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
  final byte[] decryptedmess = ciph.doFinal(encrypted);

  return new String(decryptedmess, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
}
```

Then, for trying it, this example may be valid for you:

```
final String encrypt = "My16inLengthKey5";
final byte[] docrypt = getEncrypt(encrypt, "This is a phrase to be encrypted!");
final String douncrypt = getDecrypt(encrypt.toString(), docrypt);
Log.d("Decryption", "Decrypted phrase: " + douncrypt);
```

Of course, `douncrypt` must match `This is a phrase to be encrypted!`

Comment: I am getting "Call requires API level 9" for getBytes. What can I do for Android KitKat API 19? And Also I get the same thing for this line " new String(decryptedmess, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));"