# Java: StreamCorruptedException occur when Decrypt object with DES

Tags: java, android, encryption, des

I have two method for Encrypt-save and decrypt-load Object from file in Android Internal Storage.

Encrypt and save process is done without any problem, but when I want to load the object `StreamCorruptedException` occurs in `inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(cipherInputStream);`

I searched SO more and more but I did't find a solution for my problem. all other solutions are for socket life or like this.

my code is below:

```
private static byte[] iv = { (byte) 0xB1, (byte) 0x15, (byte) 0xB5,
        (byte) 0xB7, (byte) 0x66, (byte) 0x43, (byte) 0x2F, (byte) 0xA4,
        (byte) 0xB1, (byte) 0x15, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0xC7, (byte) 0x66,
        (byte) 0x58, (byte) 0x2F, (byte) 0x5F };
```

save method: (work well)

```
private static String saveToFile(Serializable object, String fileName,
        Context ctx) {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = null;
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();
        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        SealedObject sealedObject = null;
        sealedObject = new SealedObject(object, cipher);
        CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = null;

        FileOutputStream fos = ctx.openFileOutput(fileName,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(
                new BufferedOutputStream(fos), cipher);
        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = null;
        outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(cipherOutputStream);
        outputStream.writeObject(sealedObject);
        outputStream.close();

        return "Save Complete!";

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Load method: (can't load object from `cipherInputStream`)

```
private static Serializable loadFromFile(String fileName, Context ctx) {
    Cipher cipher = null;
    Serializable userList = null;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");

        // Code to write your object to file
        SecretKey key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();
        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = null;

        FileInputStream fos = ctx.openFileInput(fileName);
        cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
                fos), cipher);

        ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;
        inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(cipherInputStream);
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        SealedObject sealedObject = null;
        sealedObject = (SealedObject) inputStream.readObject();
        userList = (Serializable) sealedObject.getObject(cipher);
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    }
    return userList;
}
```

public methods for save and load:

```
public Serializable loadPlayer(Context ctx) {
    return loadFromFile("player.dat", ctx);
}

public String savePlayer(Player player, Context ctx) {
    return saveToFile(player, "player.dat", ctx);

}
```

Comment: Aren't you generating a new random key each time you use the save or load methods?

Comment: as per @jarnbjo comment you must decrypt using the same key that you encrypt with. Currently your decrypt code generates its own key. That *can't* work.

Comment: Why are you encrypting twice? Do you *know* you're encrypting twice? Get rid of either the SealedObject or the Cipher streams.

Comment: What is worse, you are not only encrypting twice, you are using the same `Cipher` object inside `SealedObject` and cipher stream. What is the state of the cipher and what is the output of each individual operation is anyone guess.

Comment: Not anyone's guess really. The encrypting cipher first encrypts the SealedObject and then the CipherOutputStream. The decrypting cipher decrypts first the CipherInputStream and then the SealedObject. So the decrypting cipher has to deal initially with state resulting from two encryptions, followed by state from the first of those encryptions. It is just not going to work. In any case it wouldn't add any significant amount of security even if it did work.

Comment: many thanks all, can you explain more about twice encryption? I use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691796/encrypted-save-and-decrypted-load-of-an-arraylist-of-serializable-objects solution, if it possible give me a correct example for doing this work or give me a good reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making at least two major mistakes.

1. You have to use the same key to decrypt as you used to encrypt. You can't just generate a random key and except it to be able to decrypt anything. Cryptology isn't magic. You will have to arrange for the decryption key to be preserved somehow, transmitted if necessary, *securely,* and used at the decryption step.
2. You're encrypting once with the `SealedObject` and again with the `CipherOutputStream`; then in the reverse direction you're decrypting once with the `CipherInputStream` and again via the `SealedObject`. This won't actually work, because the `Cipher` object isn't in comparable states at sender and receiver, and in any case it's pointless. Lose either the SealedObject or the Cipher streams.